# How to mock with FakeItEasy Sportradar IOddsFeed ProducerUp event

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have problem to mock object, instance of IOddsFeed interface of Sportradar package

I mocked up IOddsFeed interface

```
// Odds feed mock implementation 
var oddsFeed = A.Fake<IOddsFeed>(o => o.Strict());

// oddsFeed builder
A.CallTo(() => oddsFeed.CreateBuilder()).Returns(A.Fake<IoddsFeedSessionBuilder>());
A.CallTo(() => oddsFeed.CreateBuilder()).SetMessageInterest(null)).Returns(null);

// PROBLEM - I need to mock EVENT ProducerUp(and others)
```

> This event is automatically called by OddsEvents "Raised when the current IOddsFeed instance determines that the IProducer associated with the odds feed went up (back online)"
> I'm using the latest one version

So I need to mock event, I checked documentation tried few things from internet and documentation but I couldn't make a solution